# How to change FireFox profile via Selenium to set devtools.jsonview.enabled=false

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, json-view, devtools.jsonview.enabled, setpreference

From Firefox 53, the JSON viewer is enabled by default in Beta and the normal release version of Firefox.
if you want to get JSON data from selenium need to disable **jsonview**
the question is how to disable that

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
import { Browser, Builder, By } from "selenium-webdriver";
import Firefox from "selenium-webdriver/firefox.js";


const options = new Firefox.Options();
const builder = new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.FIREFOX);
options.setPreference("devtools.jsonview.enabled", false);
options.addArguments(`--ignore-certificate-errors`);
options.addArguments(`--ignore-ssl-errors`);
builder.setFirefoxOptions(options);
driver = builder.build();
```